# How do I store multiple checkbox data in a list of array?

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a Django form with multiple checkbox that looks like this:

[multiple checkbox form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGp8G.png)

I've manage to store the data in multiple separate columns:

[picture of the data row in my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jEUc.png)

My question is how can I store the multiple checkbox data in a single column instead of multiple separate columns?

**Here's the checkbox's HTML**

```
<label class="form-control acl-label">Project Management</label>
<div><input class="project" value="listing" name="project[]" type="checkbox" id="project-listing.{{user.id}}"> <label for="project-listing.{{user.id}}">Listing</label></div>
<div><input class="project" value="create" name="project[]" type="checkbox" id="project-create.{{user.id}}"> <label for="project-create.{{user.id}}">Create</label></div>
<div><input class="project" value="edit" name="project[]" type="checkbox" id="project-edit.{{user.id}}"> <label for="project-edit.{{user.id}}">Edit</label></div>
<div><input class="project" value="delete" name="project[]" type="checkbox" id="project-delete.{{user.id}}"> <label for="project-delete.{{user.id}}">Delete</label></div> <br/>
```

**Here's the code for my view.py file**

```
project_mgmt = request.POST.getlist('project[]')
engagement_mgmt = request.POST.getlist('engagement[]')
issue_mgmt = request.POST.getlist('issue[]')
user_mgmt = request.POST.getlist('user[]')
reporting_mgmt = request.POST.getlist('reporting[]')
setting = request.POST.getlist('setting[]')
audit_log = request.POST.getlist('audit[]')

AccessControl.objects.filter(uid_uname=user_id).update(project_mgmt=project_mgmt, engagement_mgmt=engagement_mgmt, issue_mgmt=issue_mgmt, 
user_mgmt=user_mgmt, reporting_mgmt=reporting_mgmt, setting=setting, audit_log=audit_log)
```

**models.py**

```
class AccessControl(models.Model):
    uid_index = models.ForeignKey(UserDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    uid_uname = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None)
    project_mgmt = models.TextField(default=None, null=True)
    engagement_mgmt = models.TextField(default=None, null=True)
    issue_mgmt = models.TextField(default=None, null=True)
    user_mgmt = models.TextField(default=None, null=True)
    reporting_mgmt = models.TextField(default=None, null=True)
    setting = models.TextField(default=None, null=True)
    audit_log  = models.TextField(default=None, null=True)
```

Comment: I think you could save the form data as a dictionary then save it to the model as string/JSON, then when you want to get the data, use ast.literal_eval

Comment: Maybe: put a property with getter and setter methods on your model, to convert between the human-friendly(?) array representation, and (say) an `IntegerField` with the tickboxes encoded as a bitmap?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to store the checkbox data in a single column in my database. Here's what I did:

**HTML**

Give the same value for the name attribute for all the checkbox.

```
<div>
<label class="form-control acl-label">Project Management</label>
<div><input class="project" value="project-listing" name="permissions[]" type="checkbox" id="project-listing.{{user.id}}" {% if 'project-listing' in user.permissions %} checked {% endif %}> <label for="project-listing.{{user.id}}" >Listing</label></div>
<div><input class="project" value="project-create" name="permissions[]" type="checkbox" id="project-create.{{user.id}}" {% if 'project-create' in user.permissions %} checked {% endif %}> <label for="project-create.{{user.id}}">Create</label></div>
<div><input class="project" value="project-edit" name="permissions[]" type="checkbox" id="project-edit.{{user.id}}" {% if 'project-edit' in user.permissions %} checked {% endif %}> <label for="project-edit.{{user.id}}">Edit</label></div>
<div><input class="project" value="project-delete" name="permissions[]" type="checkbox" id="project-delete.{{user.id}}" {% if 'project-delete' in user.permissions %} checked {% endif %}> <label for="project-delete.{{user.id}}">Delete</label></div> <br/>
</div>

<div>
<label class="form-control acl-label">Engagement Management</label>
<div><input class="engagement" value="engagement-allListing" name="permissions[]" type="checkbox" id="engagement-allListing.{{user.id}}" {% if 'engagement-allListing' in user.permissions %} checked {% endif %}> <label for="engagement-allListing.{{user.id}}">All Listing</label> </div>
<div><input class="engagement" value="engagement-listing" name="permissions[]" type="checkbox" id="engagement-listing.{{user.id}}" {% if 'engagement-listing' in user.permissions %} checked {% endif %}> <label for="engagement-listing.{{user.id}}">Listing</label></div>
<div><input class="engagement" value="engagement-create" name="permissions[]" type="checkbox" id="engagement-create.{{user.id}}" {% if 'engagement-create' in user.permissions %} checked {% endif %}> <label for="engagement-create.{{user.id}}">Create</label></div>
<div><input class="engagement" value="engagement-edit" name="permissions[]" type="checkbox" id="engagement-edit.{{user.id}}" {% if 'engagement-edit' in user.permissions %} checked {% endif %}> <label for="engagement-edit.{{user.id}}">Edit</label></div>
<div><input class="engagement" value="engagement-delete" name="permissions[]" type="checkbox" id="engagement-delete.{{user.id}}" {% if 'engagement-delete' in user.permissions %} checked {% endif %}> <label for="engagement-delete.{{user.id}}">Delete</label></div> <br/>
</div>
```

**submit function in views.py**

Here, my submit function update the database and store the checkbox data in arrays

```
permissions = request.POST.getlist('permissions[]')
AccessControl.objects.filter(uid_uname=user_id).update(permissions=permissions)
```

Also, remember to change the **models.py** to store the data in Textfield, like this:

```
permissions = models.TextField(default=None, null=True)
```

The end result looks like this: [Checkbox data in arrays using single database column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNkgg.png)

I hope this will help others facing the same issue. Happy coding! :)